# a break in a table

Tags: php, html

i need to break them up

```
||name  || id || 
__________________
||tab || 1||
||ritchie|| 2||
__________________
_________________
||apple|| 3
```

if i use tr td,
it would end up as

```
||tab || 1||
||ritchie|| 2||
__________________
_______||_________
||apple|| 3
```

ther ewould be a line in the break too.

how to achieve the one whole single row thing?

thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, can you provide more information? Maybe use `<pre>` to create a better illustration?

Comment: When you determine the correct answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for colspan="2", but it's awfully hard to tell without seeing some source.